# .net WebService method with "[SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true)]" Cause Thread Aborted

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a .net Web Service. All the web methods require to be [SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true)]".
But with this setting the web service process gets aborted abruptly.

System Configuration:
net 2.0
IIS 5.1

Exception message:
"Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call"

Comment: Please show some code. Maybe tell us how you know the process gets aborted. Maybe post an exception if there is one.

Comment: I attach to aspnet_wp.exe process for steeping through web service code. The process aborts after executing few statements.

Answer (score 0):

This error can appear when you have a combination of try catch blocks and redirect statements.

Try commenting out your try catch statements.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160605104320/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/vadivelkumar/archive/2006/02/25/70703.aspx)